# Django model db insert sometimes fails with unknown encoding error

Tags: python, mysql, django, encoding

I have a large program that uses Django as a backend workflow manager that calls various Python scripts that run C-compiled .so shared libraries.

One such portion of the program involves profiling the stages, so generally it populates a MySQL db table with execution parameters, then after the stage is run populates another table with run times, file sizes, etc.

General code is like:

```
from profiler.models import ProfileParameters, ProfileData, ProfileResults

# Populate dB with execution parameters
 ProfileData(profile_id=profile_number, profile_type=1, profile_param_id=1, profile_param_value=data).save()

# The above line always works

# call C .so
run_program.argtypes(...) # details ommited for brevity

# get run_times, etc.
run_time = get_runtimes()
total_file_size = get_filesize()

# Try to populate dB again
ProfileResults(profile_id=profile_number, profile_filesize_MB=total_file_size, profile_process_time_minutes = run_time).save()
```

The script *sometimes* has a problem with the last call to ProfileResults(). Sometimes it works, while other times it does not. When it does not work, I see the error:

```
    ProfileResults(profile_id=profile_number, profile_filesize_MB=total_file_size, profile_process_time_minutes = total_time_minutes).save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 157, in execute
    query = query.encode(charset)
LookupError: unknown encoding: PEh
```

So, the key thing, I think is:

LookupError: unknown encoding: PEh

The actual error, in this case includes a character that won't print out here. But what is printed out after "unknown encoding" changes, and sometimes it is blank.

I think that somehow the encoding is changing when the .so is running and printing to stdout.

I tried putting:

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Before the call to ProfileResults(), but that didn't seem to work.

The strangest thing, I think, is that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. But it seems that it mostly doesn't work.

Also what is input in the call to ProfileResults() doesn't seem to matter. If I place a pdb.set_trace() right before it, and call it with just hard-coded values rather than variables, the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue has to do with MySQL global cursor, where undefined stuff can happen upon repeated DB connection opening and closings. Don't know if I fully understand it...

Anyways, the shared library .so that the Python script was calling also performed some database transactions, so opened and closed a connection. The Python script, upon returning from the .so was experiencing some strange behavior.

It came down to looking in /usr/lib/Python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py, line 155:

```
charset = db.character_set_name()
```

This was returning the blank, or sometimes gibberish, or sometimes correct values. Hardcoding this to 'utf-8' fixed the problem, but naturally isn't a good solution.

So, what seemed to work was restarting the Django connection upon returning from the .so:

```
from django import db
db.close_connection()
from profiler.models import ProfileParameters, ProfileData, ProfileResults
```

So far, everything has been working as expected now. It is somewhat irksome not fully understanding the problem, and why this solution works, but good to know it does. Is it a Django bug, MySQL bug, or not a bug at all?

Anyone have more information about this?